# ASP.Net Core 2.0 - Visual Studio MVC Template - Where are the controller actions?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

I created a new ASP.Net Core 2.0 web application in Visual Studio 2017 using the MVC template with individual database accounts for authentication.

I've been looking through the source code to find how uses the `SignInManager` and `UserManager` to do registration and login.

I think it's using Razor Pages, but cannot find the underlying code.  I would expect that it has to reference the manager classes (and view models) somewhere.

However, I cannot find any controller actions that perform these operations.  The `AccountController` only has one method and it does a logout.

Does anyone know where the routes are implemented for registration and logn?

Comment: It could be in the Startup class or in the controller (attribute routing)

Comment: I think it's using Razor Pages (page/view without controller), but don't understand where the underlying code is

Comment: Pages folder and there will be a view file and it's class

Comment: Thaks, I just found it like 10 seconds before you posted your comment

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it.

The Razor Page has a "code behind" file e.g. `Register.cshtml` and `Register.cshtml.cs`.